# How to use dependency resolver?

Tags: c#, architecture, dependency-injection

I've a little problem. For a lossless architecture I use dependency injection.
How can I share this dependency resolver between my other classes? Should this resolver a static class with a global static list of some instances, or should I do this non static and pass this resolver over a property or a constructor to other classes? I think, you should do this non static, because if you do this with a singleton static resolver, you've a dependency to this resolver.

Comment: Sry, I'm a .Net-Developer

Comment: Can you tag it and remember to tag always ..

Comment: It doesnt matter which languages, the princibe of DI ist always the same. I only want to know, how other class should have access to a resolver. With passing in a constructor or with a static resolver.

Comment: Most of the time clases shouldn't access to a resolver. Abusing is known as the Service Locator Antipatern.

Comment: Typical use of a service locator is by static property: https://commonservicelocator.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Consuming%20the%20Interface&referringTitle=Home

Comment: Classes express their dependencies in their constructor, and the io container takes care to provide them.

Answer (score 1):

You could have two types of resolver.

- One where your dependencies gets resolved using constructor like:

  ```
  MyClass myClass;
  public MyConstructor(MyClass myClass) {
     this.myClass = myClass;
  }
  ```
- Or other way is to use setter injection using setter method like:

  ```
  public void setMyClass(MyClass myClas) {
       this.myClass = myClass;
  }
  ```

There are other design patterns like factory or singleton which uses static method and based on input parameter they produce different object which you could use as well but its altogether different from DI and can help in DI.

Comment: Its actual dependency of your class. Your class should not concentrate on how to get my dependancies rather should focus on business logic.

Comment: @Macel, no. myClass is not the dependecy resolver, it's a dependency.

Answer (score 1):

A lot has been said and written about this, but the general consensus is that having a global 'resolver' (a.k.a. the [Service Locator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_locator_pattern)) is an [anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/):

> the problem with Service Locator is that it hides a class'
>   dependencies, causing run-time errors instead of compile-time errors,
>   as well as making the code more difficult to maintain because it
>   becomes unclear when you would be introducing a breaking change.

Instead of using this global resolver, you should use the oposite pattern: Dependency Injection (DI). With DI you inject the dependencies into a class, compared to letting the class request the dependency through some resolver. The most common -and usually best- way to do this is using constructor injection. This means that the constructor of some class defines the dependencies it requires as constructor arguments in the classes [sole constructor](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=97).

The classes constructor should only contain dependencies that this class uses directly. Dependencies that are needed by the classes dependencies should not be exposed to that class, because that would only unneedlessly increase coupling of your code and make your code harder to test, harder to reason about.

Result of this is that non of the classes in your application will be responsible for building up and requesting their dependencies. Each class pushes this responsibility up the call chain, resulting in having one single place in the application, near the startup path of your application, that is responsible for building all object graphs: the [composition root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/).

The composition root is the place where you might use such a resolver, but this is optional.